# What should be the type of this Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I have to write a Haskell function in order to check out if the triangle is valid.I just cannot figure the type of the functions.Here is my work.

```
isvalidtriangle : : integer -> integer -> integer ->bool
isvalidtriangle a b c (a+b>c)&&(a+c>b)&&(b+c>a)
```

it always shows errors and i cannot see the logic behind that how this function helps to calculate the area of triangle later (there is area of triangle function after this one ) Thanks in advance and I am very tired ,I have no idea how it can be down.

Comment: Could you 1. format your code 2. show the errors you get (though I see there should be many) 3. Tell us where you got this function since it evidently wasn't written by you.

Comment: (1) You're missing an equality sign between `a b c` and `(a+b>c)`. (2) types in Haskell are capitalized. `Integer` and `Bool`, not `integer` and `bool`. (3) there is an extra space between the two colons.

Comment: Also, I suggest to lowerCamelCase the name of the function, hence `isValidTriangle`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of things to help you out:

1. Keep your colons together, i.e. :: instead of : :
2. Haskell types start with capital letters, so you should do

   isvalidtriangle :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
3. As others have said, you need an equals sign before you write the body of the function. Also, ***camelCase*** is better than ***alllowercase*** with no separators for readability purposes.

The final code becomes:

```
isValidTriangle :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
isValidTriangle a b c = (a+b>c)&&(a+c>b)&&(b+c>a)
```

Comment: Thanks，this question was written in a messy , I should not write this question with exhausted mind. Actually I did everything you mentioned but thank you nonetheless, the real question is that how I can write a function definition so that it fits the function types， assuming the type I put here is correct.And second question is that after this "test" , how to combine the calculation function so that It can filter the invalid values and continue to calculate. : )